# Parentheses is Invalid Bash

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I use windows generally for development, so I am not familiar with shell commands. But I have this shell file which I intend to use to  start mongo containers on docker, here is what is in the file

```
//docker.sh
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.mongo.yml up -d
docker exec -it localmongo1 mongo


rs.initiate( // over here
  {
    _id : 'rs0',
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "mongo1:27017" },
      { _id : 1, host : "mongo2:27017" },
      { _id : 2, host : "mongo3:27017", arbiterOnly: true }
    ]
  }
)
```

When I run the file `docker.sh`, I get this error `( is invalid, did you forget to escape it`. I have tried using the backslash key `\` but it doesn't work. I don't know what else to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is `rs.initiate(`? That's not valid shell syntax at all. Is this supposed to be a command to be executed in the Mongo client?

Comment: @knittl Yes, It's a command to be executed in the mongo container.

Comment: `docker exec -it localmongo1 mongo << EOF
your_mongo_code
EOF` - this should work if mongo will read commands from strding